# Problem with filling ext grid with JSON values

Tags: java, json, extjs, grid

I'm new in [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_%28JavaScript_library%29) and I have a problem: I'm trying to fill extjs-grid with data:

```
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            root: 'topics',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount',
            idProperty: 'threadid',
            remoteSort: true,
            autoLoad: true, ///

            fields: [
                'title', 'forumtitle', 'forumid', 'author',
                {name: 'replycount', type: 'int'},
                {name: 'lastpost', mapping: 'lastpost', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
                'lastposter', 'excerpt'
            ],

            proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
            url:'http://10.10.10.101:8080/myproject/statusList/getJobs/2-10/search-jobname-/sort-asdf/filterjobname-123/filterusername-davs/filterstatus-completed/filtersubmdate-today',
            method : 'GET'
        })
    });

    //
    var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
        {sortable:true, id : 'id',          dataIndex:'id'},
        {sortable:true, id : 'title',       dataIndex:'title'},
        {sortable:true, id : 'forumtitle',  dataIndex:'forumtitle'},
        {sortable:true, id : 'forumid',     dataIndex:'forumid'},
        {sortable:true, id : 'author',      dataIndex:'author'}
    ]);

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id: 'mainGrid',
        el:'mainPageGrid',
        pageSize:10,
        store:store,
        //    stripeRows: true,
        cm:cm,
        stateful: false, // skipSavingSortState
        viewConfig:{
            forceFit:true
        },
        //        width:1000,
        //        height:700,
        loadMask:true,
        frame:false,

        bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
            id : 'mainGridPaginator',
            store:store,
            hideRefresh : true,
            plugins: new Ext.ux.Andrie.pPageSize({
                beforeText: 'View: ',
                afterText: '',
                addAfter: '-',
                variations: [10, 25, 50, 100, 1000]
                //comboCfg: {
                    //id: '${ dispview_widgetId }_bbar_pageSize'
                //}
            }),
            displayMsg: 'Displaying items {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg:'No data found',
            displayInfo:true
        })
    });

    grid.render();
});
```

and the Java part:

```
@GET
@Path("/getJobs/{startFrom}-{startTo}/search-{searchType}-{searchName:.*}/" +
        "sort-{sortType}/filterjobname-{filterJobName:.*}/filterusername-{filterUsername:.*}/" +
        "filterstatus-{filterStatus:.*}/filtersubmdate-{filterSubmittedDate:.*}")
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Encoded
public String getJobs(
        @PathParam("startFrom")             String startFrom,
        @PathParam("startTo")               String startTo,
        @PathParam("searchType")            String searchType,
        @PathParam("searchName")            String searchName,
        @PathParam("sortType")              String sortType,
        @PathParam("filterJobName")         String filterJobName,
        @PathParam("filterUsername")        String filterUsername,
        @PathParam("filterStatus")          String filterStatus,
        @PathParam("filterSubmittedDate")   String filterSubmittedDate) {


    return "{totalCount:'3',topics:[{title:'XTemplate with in EditorGridPanel',threadid:'133690',username:'kpremco',userid:'272497',dateline:'1305604761',postid:'602876',forumtitle:'Ext 3x Help',forumid:'40',replycount:'2',lastpost:'1305857807',lastposter:'kpremco',excerpt:'Hi I have an EditiorGridPanel whose one column i am using XTemplate to render and another Column is Combo Box FieldWhen i render the EditorGri'}," +
                                             "{title:'IFrame error _flyweights is undefined',threadid:'133571',username:'Daz',userid:'52119',dateline:'1305533577',postid:'602456',forumtitle:'Ext 3x Help',forumid:'40',replycount:'1',lastpost:'1305857313',lastposter:'Daz',excerpt:'For Ext 330 using Firefox 4  Firebug, the following error is often happening when our app loads e._flyweights is undefined Yetthis '}," +
                                             "{title:'hellllllllllllllpwhy it doesnt fire cellclick event after I change the cell value',threadid:'133827',username:'aimer311',userid:'162000',dateline:'1305700219',postid:'603309',forumtitle:'Ext 3x Help',forumid:'40',replycount:'3',lastpost:'1305856996',lastposter:'aimer311',excerpt:'okI will discribe this problem as more detail as I canI look into this problem for a whole dayI set clicksToEdit1 to a EditorGridPanelso when I'}]}";
```

As a result I'm getting a JavaScript error:

```
Syntax error at line 1 while loading:
totalCount:'3',topics:[{title:'XTemplate
---------------------^
expected ';', got ':'
```

Although, when I'm using Proxy's URL:

```
URL: 'http://extjs.com/forum/topics-browse-remote.php',
```

which represents same information, I don't have any problems.

Where is my failure????

P.S. Comments for the first answer:

```
    return "{\"totalCount\":\"3\",\"topics\":[{\"title\":\"XTemplate with in EditorGridPanel\",\"threadid\":\"133690\",\"username\":\"kpremco\",\"userid\":\"272497\",\"dateline\":\"1305604761\",\"postid\":\"602876\",\"forumtitle\":\"Ext 3x Help\",\"forumid\":\"40\",\"replycount\":\"2\",\"lastpost\":\"1305857807\",\"lastposter\":\"kpremco\",\"excerpt\":\"Hi I have an EditiorGridPanel whose one column i am using XTemplate to render and another Column is Combo Box FieldWhen i render the EditorGri\"}," +
                                             "{\"title\":\"IFrame error _flyweights is undefined\",\"threadid\":\"133571\",\"username\":\"Daz\",\"userid\":\"52119\",\"dateline\":\"1305533577\",\"postid\":\"602456\",\"forumtitle\":\"Ext 3x Help\",\"forumid\":\"40\",\"replycount\":\"1\",\"lastpost\":\"1305857313\",\"lastposter\":\"Daz\",\"excerpt\":\"For Ext 330 using Firefox 4  Firebug, the following error is often happening when our app loads e._flyweights is undefined Yet, this \"}," +
                                             "{\"title\":\"hellllllllllllllpwhy it doesn't fire cellclick event after I change the cell value\",\"threadid\":\"133827\",\"username\":\"aimer311\",\"userid\":\"162000\",\"dateline\":\"1305700219\",\"postid\":\"603309\",\"forumtitle\":\"Ext 3x Help\",\"forumid\":\"40\",\"replycount\":\"3\",\"lastpost\":\"1305856996\",\"lastposter\":\"aimer311\",\"excerpt\":\"okI will discribe this problem as more detail as I canI look into this problem for a whole dayI set clicksToEdit1 to a EditorGridPanelso when I\"}]}";
```

I've got the following error:

```
Syntax error at line 1 while loading:
{"totalCount":"3","topics":[{"title
-------------^
expected ';', got ':'
```

P.S. #2. When I've added '[' to the begining of the response string and ']' to the end , erros disappered, but grid hasn't been filled with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root of issue.

As I've known Ext send to my web service function with parameter 'callback=[some_callback_name]' (e.g. callback1001). It means that Extjs wanna to get results not just in JSON format, but in format 'callback1001()'. When I've return my data in this format everything became good.

Proof links:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?22990-Json-Invalid-label   (response #6)
- http://indiandeve.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/extjs-error-invalid-label-error-while-using-scripttagproxy-for-json-data-in-paging-grid-example/

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning (valid) JSON. Refer to the [JSON site](http://json.org) for details, but for instance, all property keys must be in double quotes. (All strings must also be in double quotes; single quotes are not valid for JSON strings.)

So for instance, this is **not** valid JSON:

```
{totalCount:'3'}
```

...because the key is not in quotes, and the value is using single quotes. The correct JSON would be:

```
{"totalCount":"3"}
```

...if you really want the `3` to be a string, or:

```
{"totalCount":3}
```

...if the `3` should be a number.

People frequently confuse JSON and JavaScript's object literal notation, but they are different. Specifically, JSON is a *subset* of object literal notation. A lot of things that are valid in object literal notation are not valid in JSON. Any time you're in doubt, you can check at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com), which provides a proper JSON validator.

Comment: I've commented in end of my question

Comment: @davs: You're still not returning valid JSON (you've missed out some quotes, such as around "topics", and there may be other issues). So the first thing is to make sure you really return valid JSON. I suspect something else is also going on, but that's the first step.

Comment: Thanks a lot for JSON validator, I have changed returning string again,  but even if it says that the JSON is valid, I have problems ....

Comment: @davs: Yeah, your latest update is now valid JSON, so at least you've eliminated that.

Comment: But still I'm getting error 'expected ';', got ':'' (as I've described in end of question)

Comment: @davs: I know, I don't know enough about ExtJS or the other technologies you're using to help further. Hopefully now that the JSON stuff is out of the way, someone will.